# Why does my v-select render more than once?

Tags: vue.js, components, vuex, vuetify.js

I'm working with vuex and vuetify, so I'd like to do a dropdown-list with items from my server.
I get a Json-object, which returns as an array of objects from my store.
I use the getter, to access it all in my component, and it looks fine, except that the dropdown-list renders more than once (20+ times at the moment in my component). How do I get my dropdownlist just to render once?

```
<template>
<v-select v-for"item in allItems" :key="item.name"
:items="allItems" item-value="id" item-text="name">
{{item}}</v-select
</template>

<script>
computed: {
allItems(){
return this.$store.getters['items'];
}
}
</script>
```

Everything is compiling, but I really don't need more than one dropdown list. What Am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `v-for="item in allItems"` in your `<v-select>`. This will render a `<v-select>` element for each item in `allItems`.

Comment: Thank you, that was the solution to my problem.